# Error with Swift and Core Data: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(entity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)'

Tags: cocoa, core-data, swift, initialization

I have the following class that inherits from `NSManagedObject`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


class Note: NSManagedObject {



    @NSManaged var text: String
    @NSManaged var name: String


     init(name: String, text:String, context: NSManagedObjectContext){

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: context);
        super.init(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        self.text = text
        self.name = name;

    }
}
```

When I create instances of it, everything works fine, but when I make a search for these entities, I get a very odd error:

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(entity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)'
```

This is the code that causes the error:

```
func coreDatePlayground(){

    var note = Note(name: "A new note", text: "blah", context: self.managedObjectContext!)

    println("\(note.name)  \(note.text)")

    var noote2 = Note(name: "Another note", text: "blah blah", context: self.managedObjectContext!)


    managedObjectContext?.save(nil)

    var fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Note")
    // This line causes the crash.
    var results = self.managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetch, error: nil)
    if let objects = results{
        println(objects.count)
    }

}
```

I found out that changing the initialiser by making it a convenience one and calling on self instead of on super gets rid of the issue, but I have no idea why.

```
 convenience init(name: String, text:String, context: NSManagedObjectContext){

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: context);
    self.init(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

    self.text = text
    self.name = name;

}
```

The code above works, but I have no idea why. Anybody knows what's going on? Is it a bug or is my fault?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I don't feel like the answer gives a proper explanaiton.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_331) behavior.

> Swift subclasses do not inherit their superclass initializers by default

For example, following code does not even compile, because `Child` does not inherit `init(id:String)` automatically. This mechanism make sure `name` in `Child` class properly initialized.

```
class Parent {
    var id:String
    init(id:String) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

class Child:Parent {
    var name:String
    init(id:String, name:String) {
        self.name = name
        super.init(id: id)
    }
}

var child1 = Child(id:"child1")
```

If you define only `convenience` initializers in subclass, then it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers as documented in "Automatic Initializer Inheritance" section

Comment: But how does his first code compile then? It doesn't include all designated initializers right?

Answer (score 13):

You must implement the following in your `NSManagedObject` subclass (this is the Swift 3.0 version):

```
@objc
private override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
}
```

The answer is kind of answering it, but not really directly.

The reasoning for this is that Swift does not inherit their supercalls designated initializers by default **AND** it seems as CoreData by uses this initializer when doing fetches (insert a breakpoint in the method to see). So here we "bring up" the designated initializer for CoreData to use.

If you have `NSManagedObject` base classes, you must also implement this method in those.

[Credits to JSQCoreDataKit for the idea](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQCoreDataKit/blob/develop/Example/ExampleModel/ExampleModel/Employee.swift).

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much, really you save my time after a 3 hrs investigation, I've just overridden the initializer on base and child class and it works fine