# How to make a designated initializer for NSManagedObject subclass in Swift?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

```
class Alternative: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var text: String
    @NSManaged var isCorrect: Bool
    @NSManaged var image: NSData
} 

convenience init(text: String, isCorrect: Bool, entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) {
        let alternative = Alternative(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context) as Alternative
        alternative.text = text
        alternative.isCorrect = isCorrect
        return alternative
}
```

I want to make a method that lets me initialize new objects with this call:

```
let newAlternative = Alternative("third platform", True, entityDescription, managedObjectContext)
```

But i get the error:

```
Convenience initializer for Alternative must delegate with self.init
```

What do i need to change in my initalizer to make my example usage work?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A convenience initializer must call the designated initializer on `self`:

```
convenience init(text: String, isCorrect: Bool, entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) {
    self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    self.text = text
    self.isCorrect = isCorrect
}
```

which would be called as

```
let newAlternative = Alternative(text: "third platform", isCorrect: true,
     entity: entityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
```

In addition, you could also move the creation of the entity description into the convenience initializer instead of passing it as an argument (as motivated by
Mundi's answer):

```
convenience init(text: String, isCorrect: Bool, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Alternative", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
    self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    self.text = text
    self.isCorrect = isCorrect
}
```

Comment: Quick additional question @martin-r: I am trying to place these into an extension onto NSManagedObject. Do you think this should this be possible, as I'm getting a compile error. It seems to be looking for the NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER from NSManagedObject.h to be used. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Damien: Not without seeing the actual code and the exact error message.

Comment: @Damien: It does not make sense to create a "Person" entity in a NSManagedObject extension. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834753/using-swift-protocols-with-generics/24839064#24839064 for an alternative (generic) approach.

Comment: Doh! You're right! Was working ok up at the "Person" level and I just pushed it down to an extension. I should have thought about it a bit more. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 10):

I simply did this with a class function:

```
class func newInstance(text: String, notes:String, 
                    context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Item {
    var item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Item", 
               inManagedObjectContext: context) as Item
    item.notes = notes
    item.text = text
    return item
}
```

which you can call like this (almost as pretty):

```
let item = Item.newInstance(text, notes:notes, context:context)
```

Comment: So its not possible to make a designated initializer with  `Alternative("third platform", True, entityDescription, managedObjectContext)` ? My opinion is that it doesnt look as good with Alternative.newInstance(...)

Comment: +1 for *not* needing to pass an entity description into the initializer.

Comment: You can give it another name to your liking instead of `newInstance()`. Also, you still want named parameters, not just a parameter list, otherwise your code will be less readable. - In summary the class method solution is not really longer or less aesthetic than other initializers.

Comment: When you call your func in the example you do not set the context?

Comment: where do you set the context, and how?

Comment: @rcat24 Typically you have the context from your controller / background service etc. That's why this function has the context as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.1** solution:

```
convenience init(text: String, isCorrect: Bool, image: NSData, moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Alternative", in: moc)
        self.init(entity: entity!, insertInto: moc)
        // vars
        self.text = text
        self.isCorrect = isCorrect
        self.image = image
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call a designated initializer from your convenience initializer.
Also, you do not return anything from any initializer.

To fulfill the rules, which are described in Apple's Swift documentation you first need a designated initializer for your subclass, which calls the init() of its superclass, then you can offer a convenience initializer which is only allowed to call a designated initializer from its class declaration.

This would work: (**Updated: Taken into account that core data properties marked with @NSManaged are initialized automatically by the runtime.** Thanks @Martin R)

```
init(text: String, isCorrect: Bool, image: NSData, entity: NSEntityDescription,   insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
}

convenience init(text: String, isCorrect: Bool, entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) {
    self.init(text: text, isCorrect: isCorrect, entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
}
```

Comment: Core data properties (marked with `@NSManaged`) are initialized automatically by the runtime.

Comment: This will cause a problem. see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202346/error-with-swift-and-core-data-fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-i