# What does it take for NSArrayController subclass to add Core Data objects?

Tags: core-data, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

Background:   I built an app w/ inexperience. It uses bindings, a NSArrayController subclass and Core Data/iCloud. The experience level caused a lot of code unnecessary writing, yet the app worked ok. A button linked to the NSArrayController `add:` method triggered `newObject` and `addObject:`. Removing never worked and led me to look at `contentArray` binding . A week ago, I began cleaning the app to more thoroughly use the simplicity of bindings. (Unfortunately, complexity also entered into this problem.)

Assumptions:   1) `add:` and `remove:` methods would automagically fire the methods to create and delete objects. Many simple tutorials seem to work this way. 2) The `add:`, `addObject:`, `remove:` and `removeObject:` methods ***do not*** need to be overridden.

Problem:   `addObject:` and `removeObject:` do not get called (after some point of change) unless they are explicitly called in the `add:` or `remove:` method.  I have never had the functionality of deleting both the array controller and managed object with a simple click on a remove button.

Question:   What is required for the Core Data managed objects to be added and removed?

Other info:   The array controller pictured below has Custom Class set to CheckinArrayController. The Core Data stack is initialized in AppDelegate. The `newObject` method has been overridden to preset some attributes.

EDIT: Override in array controller subclass `add:`, `newObject`, `addObject:`, and `arrangeObjects:`

Code in Array Controller (NSArrayController subclass)

```
@implementation CheckinArrayController

- (id)newObject {
    id newObject = [super newObject];
    //  do object set up here ....
    return newObject;
}

- (void)add:(id)sender {
    /*  without the next 2 no object is added, although this is called
        NSManagedObject *newItem = [self newObject];
       [self addObject:newItem];    */
}

- (void)addObject:(id)object {
    [super addObject:object];
}

- (void)remove:(id)sender {
    [super remove:sender];
}

- (void)removeObject:(id)object {
    [super removeObject:object];
}

@end
```

Current array controller connections:

[image]

Comment: Did you put the array controller in Entity Mode?

Comment: Yes. With the entity name 'Checkin' (from data model) and Prepares Content checked.

Comment: Btw if you bind `Selection Indexes` of the table view to the array controller, you can bind `enabled` of the buttton to `canRemove` of the array controller. Same for the add button and `canAdd`.

Comment: Which methods did you override?

Comment: @Willeke  See edit to OP.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @Willeke  Before adding code, can you confirm my assumptions are true?  I am concerned that code will hide this issue.

Comment: Your assumptions are true. That's why I'm interested in your overrides. Do the buttons work without the overrides?

Comment: @Willeke  No. If I comment/remove the methods `add:` and `addObject`, nothing happens.  See edit.

Comment: Is there a chance that the delegate object in your xib is not the actual application delegate?  If you bind the MOC through the application with a keypath of `delegate.managedObjectContext` does the behavior of the app improve?

Comment: @stevesliva No. It doesn't matter when I bind Delegate.managedObjectContext, Delegate.self.managedObjectContext or Application.delegate.managedObjectContext.  They all display objects and only call `add:` or `remove:`

Comment: `add:` doesn't do anything. Maybe I don't understand the problem. What do you mean by "`addObject:` and `removeObject:` do not get called (after some point of change)"?

Comment: @Willeke  Thanks for persistence. Prior to a point of redesigning the application, `addObject:` and `removeObject:` were called automatically after `add:` and `remove:`. This backs up my assumption 1. After the redesign, the array controller subclass no longer adds or removes an object without the add/removeObject methods being explicitly called. `add:` is an action connection and is called. Something is missing that causes the array controller to actually add or remove those objects. I wonder if its the contentArray binding, because this binding allows for 'deletes objects on remove'.

Comment: @David - just making sure.   If you have ever removed / modified / recreated that delegate object, you can end up with two MOCs... the one your old code talks to, separate from the one you are binding to.   Just a worthwhile point of debug.

Comment: @stevesliva  Good point. Looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a convenience init in your ManagedObject class. Here is another SO question that outlines this:

[Designated Init for Managed Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428366/how-to-make-a-designated-initalizer-for-nsmanagedobject-subclass-in-swift)

Call this init method when you want to create a new Managed Object. Your arraycontroller has a managedObjectContext from the bindings you have set up.

I use it like this:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "yourEntityName", in: managedObjectContext!)
let object = YourManagedObjectClassName(property1: "property1 entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
```

I use the stock removeObject methods in the NSArrayController base class to delete objects.

[removeObject Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsarraycontroller/1529424-removeobject?changes=_8)