# Why can't I initialize my NSManagedObject when passing it an argument?

Tags: swift, core-data, initialization

I have a class (Swift 3) in my app that contains the basic CoreData stack which I moved out of `AppDelegate`. All of the operations the app needs to perform are in another class I call `CoreDataHelper`. When the app is launched, AppDelegate creates an instance of CoreDataHelper (`let dataManager = CoreDataHelper()`) which is the only thing that talks to the stack. Then in `launchCalculatorViewController()`, `dataManager` asks the stack for a new `LiftEvent`:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    let dataManager = CoreDataHelper()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // check if data needs to be loaded and load it if needed...

      launchCalculatorViewController()    
      return true
    }

    func launchCalculatorViewController() {
      self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
      let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      if let initialViewController: CalculatorViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? CalculatorViewController {

      // create the liftEvent, the viewModel, and wire it up to the view controller
      let liftEvent = dataManager.createNewLiftEvent() // go get me a new LiftEvent
      let viewModel = calculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent(withLiftEvent: liftEvent, dataManager: dataManager)
      initialViewController.viewModel = viewModel
      initialViewController.dataManager = dataManager

      self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
      self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

here's the `createNewLiftEvent()` method in `dataManager`:

```
func createNewLiftEvent() -> LiftEvent {
    let newLiftEvent = LiftEvent(dataManager: self, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: stack.managedObjectContext)

    return newLiftEvent
}
```

and the initialization of `LiftEvent` looks like this:

```
class LiftEvent: NSManagedObject, LiftEventProtocol {

    var dataManager: CoreDataHelper!

    override func awakeFromInsert() {
        super.awakeFromInsert()

        let date = Date()
        self.date = date

        let defaultUnit = UserDefaults.weightUnit()

        if defaultUnit == "kg" {
            weight = Measurement(value: 0.0, unit: .kilograms)
            liftWeights[defaultUnit] = weight
        } else {
            weight = Measurement(value: 0.0, unit: .pounds)
            liftWeights[defaultUnit] = weight
        }

        if let defaultFormula = dataManager.fetchDefaultFormula() { // unexpected nil error thrown here
            self.formula = defaultFormula // this is an NSManagedObject 
        }                                 
    }

    convenience init(dataManager: CoreDataHelper, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "LiftEvent", in: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context) // exits after this line
        self.dataManager = dataManager // never gets executed so of course it's nil
    }
}
```

I get the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Option value" error because `dataManager` is nil at this point. I try to set it in the convenience initializer but `self.dataManager = dataManager` is never executed because it exits right after `self.init`. Of course I can't put it before `self.init` because the object has to exist before I can set the value.

I'm passing in `dataManager` in an attempt **to ensure that the Formula (also an `NSManagedObject`) and this new `LiftEvent` being created are in the same managed object context** so I can set the relationship between them in `awakeFromInsert()`. Before trying this approach it was crashing because the `LiftEvent` and `Formula` were it two different `managedObjectContexts` (even though I did a lot of looking to make sure that `dataManager` and the stack were only instantiated once). The approach above was inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428366/how-to-make-a-designated-initalizer-for-nsmanagedobject-subclass-in-swift), but I think I might not understand initialization as well as I thought I did.

How do I pass in the managed object context to create a `LiftEvent` so it's in the  same managed object context as `Formula` so the relationship can be set? Or, is the totally the wrong approach for this?

Comment: At the point `let liftEvent = dataManager.createNewLiftEvent()` is called, won't dataManager be nil? What has created it before this line?

Comment: It's not nil there because the first thing AppDelegate does is `let dataManager = CoreDataHelper()` and then `let liftEvent = dataManager.createNewLiftEvent()` is called after that. The second chunk of code is in `dataManager` and as you can see it passes itself as an argument. When I step through the convenience initializer, I can see that `self.dataManager = dataManager` is never executed because it exits that method right after `self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)`. I'll update the code to make this clearer.

Comment: I don't quite see how `dataManager` is the source of your problem.  Are you sure `entity` and `context` are valid at the point where you init the `NSManagedObject` superclass?

Comment: @PhillipMills I just checked to be sure and they appear to be valid. With a breakpoint at `super.awakeFromInsert()`, `po entity.name` gives me `Optional<String> - some : "LiftEvent"` and `po managedObjectContext` gives me `<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6000001d8420>`.