# Initializing Core Data Managed Object

Tags: swift, core-data, ios8, ios9

New to Core Data and I have two issues: Initializing an `NSManagedObject` properly and retaining its values between convenience and designated initializers.

My code in my AnalyticsEvent `NSManagedObject` subclass:

```
@NSManaged public var eventName: String?
@NSManaged public var type: String?
@NSManaged public var reference: String?
@NSManaged public var timestamp: Double

public required init() {

    // Initialize CoreData stack...
    let manager = CoreDataManager(modelName: "Analytics", storeName: "Analytics")

    // I'm not sure what I should be using to instantiate a new entity here...
    // I believe the entity(forEntityName:in:) class method should return an existing value stored in managedObjectContext...
    let event = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Event", in: manager.managedObjectContext!)

    // ... and insertNewObject(forEntityName:into:) to create a placeholder
    // for my new object until I issue saveContext() on managedObjectContext.
    // This isn't working right now, so comment out following line
    //let event = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Event", into: database.managedObjectContext!) as! AnalyticsEvent
    super.init(entity: event!, insertInto: database.managedObjectContext)

    let customProperties = CustomProperties()
    self.customPropertiesData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: properties) as Data
    self.timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
}

public convenience init(eventName: String) {
    self.init()

    // At this point the data set in my designated initializer (above),
    // the values have been lost. For example, timestamp == 0
    self.eventName = eventName
    self.type = EventType.discreteEvent
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Further investigation may reveal that maybe my convenience initializer is being invoked by the `super.init(entity:insertInto:)` call and if it is, I don't know how it finds the convenience initializer's selector... but it would explain why its value's (such as the timestamp) isn't being retained- because it's a new instance of the object?! Hmm...

**EDIT 2:**

I forgot to mention I get this runtime error when execution hits the line:

```
self.eventName = eventName
```

CoreData: error: Mutating a managed object 0x7fa2da54da90  (0x7fa2da54da40) after it has been removed from its context.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I **think** what's happening here is that you need to make `init()` also a convenience initializer, and within that call `self.init(entity: event!, insertInto: database.managedObjectContext)` (rather than `super`).</s>

Edit: I had another look at this today by trying to create a minimum working example, and failed to get an error.

I'm working with a single Entity that is a `User` that simply has a name `property`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(User)
public class User: NSManagedObject {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<User> {
        return NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?

    convenience init() {
        let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
        self.init(context: context)
        self.name = "Mathew"
    }

    convenience init(named name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

`CoreDataManager` is just the autogenerated code that Xcode but moved into it's own object:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager {

    static let shared = CoreDataManager()

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataInit")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try testing this out I get the expected behavior:

```
_ = User()
_ = User(named: "Marge")
_ = User(named: "Homer")

let fetchUsers: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()

if let results = try? CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchUsers) {
print("there are", results.count, "users")

for user in results {
    print("user is", user.name!)
}

// prints:
// Mathew
// Marge
// Homer
```

However, in the `User` class, when I moved away from the singleton to creating a new instance of `CoreDataManager` e.g.

```
//let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
let context = CoreDataManager().persistentContainer.viewContext
```

this change triggered an 'CoreData: error: Mutating a managed object after it has been removed from its context.' error.

So my second diagnosis of your error is that it's coming from not using the same persistent store coordinator (and so also, a different context).

If it's important for your persistent store to be configurable (e.g. to pass in the name of the model) then I think it would be better to transition to passing in the context to the `NSManagedObject` initializer, which seems to be more of a common CoreData pattern.

Sort of a rambling answer, but hope this time it isn't a red-herring!

Comment: Thanks but I have tried this too. No luck! It provides identical runtime errors too.

Comment: @AlexSmith I'm digging into initializers and what `@NSManaged` actually means now... Have you seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39239651/1060154 I can't vouch for it but would be quick to try!

Comment: @AlexSmith I took another investigation, fingers crossed it's in the right direction

Comment: Thank you! I will need some time before I can go over this. I'm away from my desk until tomorrow morning.