# Core Data: Can not hide NSManagedObject convenience init(content:) when overriding init(entity:, insertInto:)

Tags: swift, core-data

I think I found a weird bug in core data. I tried to hide the default initialisers from class `NSManagedObject` in my Subclass. This is no problem at first. Only you have to implement your own initialiser:

```swift
@objc(Foo)
public class Foo: NSManagedObject {
  private var object: Int = 0
  
  public init(object: Int, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: String(describing: Self.self), in: context)!
    super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    self.object = object
  }  
}
```

So the following code is not compiling as expected:

```swift
let foo = Foo(context: ...)
```

Now add another initialiser to this class like this (because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202346/error-with-swift-and-core-data-fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-i))

```swift
@objc(Foo)
public class Foo: NSManagedObject {
  private var object: Int = 0
  
  public init(object: Int, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: String(describing: Self.self), in: context)!
    super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    self.object = object
  }  

  override private init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
  }
}
```

This time, the following code compiles:

```swift
let foo = Foo(context: ...)
```

What's happening here? How can I hide this initialiser?

I posted this also on [Apple's Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727068).

Comment: Does that Foo class really compile? Don't you get a compiler error “'self' used in property access 'object' before 'super.init' call”?

Comment: You are right. My mistake. I updated my question.

Comment: `content` or `object`?

Comment: Thanks for all your hints! Fixed 2 more errors in my question. Sorry!

Comment: `NSManagedObject(context:)` is a *convenience initializer.* It is inherited by the `Foo` subclass only if all *designated* initializers are overridden – which is the case in your second code block.

Comment: That's true. I didn't know this [rule](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/initialization/#Automatic-Initializer-Inheritance). Do have an idea how I can hide the convenience initializer?

Comment: @maroony: I *think* that it is not possible. Btw, why do you want to hide that initializer?

Comment: I want to make sure, that I can not accidentally use the wrong initialiser in my further code. The inherited convenience initialiser creates unusable or invalid objects.

Comment: Don’t you need validation anyway to check if objects are valid and/or set up rules in your core data model? Maybe also check this with unit tests and perhaps also a linter. Maybe hiding an init isn’t the best or only way to handle this.

Comment: You're right. But I think it is also good practise to hide methods, that should not be used by me our others. This prevents mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) pointed out, the initialiser `Foo(context: ...)` is there because I override *all* *designated* initialisers, see [Rule 2](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/initialization/#Automatic-Initializer-Inheritance).

To hide this initialiser you can mark it as *unavailable*:

```swift
  @available(*, unavailable)
  public convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    fatalError("Initialiser is hidden!")
  }
```